# Terraform: dynamic nested groups for EKS module

Tags: dynamic, module, terraform, amazon-eks

I'm trying to configure EKS on different environments with Terraform AWS EKS module (https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/). Environments differ by number of EKS-managed node groups. I'm using list of objects to describe nodegroups in a varibale:

```
node_groups = [
  {
    "name"             = "nodegroup_name"
    "desired_capacity" = 1,
    "max_capacity"     = 3,
    "min_capacity"     = 1,
    "subnets"          = "internal",
    "instance_types"   = "r5.xlarge",
    "k8s_labels"       = {
      NodeGroup        = "internal"
    }
  }
]
```

And here's the module code for node groups definition:

```
  for_each = { for node_group in var.node_groups : node_group.name => node_group }
  eks_managed_node_groups               = {
    nodegroup={
      name                              = each.key
      desired_capacity                  = each.value.desired_capacity
      max_capacity                      = each.value.max_capacity
      min_capacity                      = each.value.min_capacity
      subnets                           = each.value.subnets != "external" ? data.aws_subnets.eks_external_subnets.ids : data.aws_subnets.eks_internal_subnets.ids
      instance_types                    = [each.value.instance_types]
      source_security_group_ids         = each.value.subnets != "external" ? [ aws_security_group.eks-external-sec-group.id ] : [ aws_security_group.eks-internal-sec-group.id ]
      capacity_type                     = "ON_DEMAND"
      k8s_labels                        = each.value.k8s_labels
      additional_tags                   = local.tags
    }
  }
```

But terraform plan returns errors:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on ../../../modules/aws/eks/main.tf line 66, in data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "this":
  66:   name = module.eks_remote.cluster_id

Inappropriate value for attribute "name": string required.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on ../../../modules/aws/eks/main.tf line 101, in locals:
 101:   ${chomp(module.eks_remote.aws_auth_configmap_yaml)}

Invalid value for "str" parameter: string required.
```

And in logs I see a lot of the following messages:
`[WARN] ReferenceTransformer: reference not found: "each.value"`

Can somebody, please, help me with this?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same. Did you make it work?

Comment: Yes, solved it via local variables:


`locals {
  eks_nodegroups = { for node_group in var.node_groups : node_group.name => {
      name                              = node_group.name
      labels                            = node_group.k8s_labels
      ....
     }
  }
}`

And in module:

`eks_managed_node_groups = local.eks_nodegroups`

Answer (score 0):

Based on OP's comment I was able to create a dynamic `eks_managed_node_groups` object. The complete solution would look something like this:

```
variable "workers" {
  type = list(object({
    name          = string
    image         = string
    instances     = list(string)
    capacity_type = optional(string)
  }))
  default = [{
    name          = "system"
    image         = "AL2023_x86_64_STANDARD"
    instances     = ["t3.small", "t3a.small"]
    capacity_type = "ON_DEMAND"
  }]
}

locals {
  vpc_cidr     = "10.0.0.0/16"
  azs          = slice(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, 0, 3)
  cluster_name = "${var.base_name}-${data.aws_region.current.name}"
  eks_nodegroups = { for node_group in var.workers : node_group.name => {
    name              = "${var.base_name}-${node_group.name}"
    iam_role_name     = "${var.base_name}-${node_group.name}-eks-node-group"
    ami_type          = node_group.image
    instance_types    = node_group.instances
    desired_size      = 1
    min_size          = 1
    max_size          = 3
    enable_monitoring = false
    capacity_type     = try(node_group.capacity_type, "ON_DEMAND")
  }}
}
```

You can use additional terrafrom functions to create defaults and fallbacks for optional values. Once your managed nodes object is generated you can just pass it to the eks module by setting `eks_managed_node_groups = local.eks_nodegroups`